# Why is shorting (oil) futures a bit of a negative gamma trade?

Tags: options, option-pricing, futures, trading, financial-engineering

From this article, http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2017-01-22/oil-speculators-have-never-been-long,

"I get what you're saying about the price risk which is always the danger of shorting crude oil it's always a bit of a negative gamma trade."

How is shorting crude oil (futures) a negative gamma trade? Im assuming there is some shadow gamma there somewhere.

Comment: With oil prices where they are nowadays, they could fall a little bit, or they might jump up quite a bit (say a war in ME, or an OPEC agreement...). So there is a certain asymmetry there when you are short CL.

Comment: @noob2 I will accept ^^^ if you make it an answer